# Python change negative values to positive values in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, numbers

this have any way to check if i have negtive values (only integers) in my dictionary?
And if yes to change all the negative values to positive values?
For example:

```
D = {'Milk': -5, 'eggs': 144, 'flour': -10, 'chocolate': -2, 'yeast': 5, 'Cornflower': 3}
```

And i want to get:

```
D = {'Milk': 5, 'eggs': 144, 'flour': 10, 'chocolate': 2, 'yeast': 5, 'Cornflower': 3}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? To answer your question, YES, there are lots of ways to do it.

Comment: Of course I tried, I didn't find the right way to used to abs in dictionary

Comment: You don't need to use `abs`. There are other easier ways to do this as you can see from the answers posted. I did not see any of your efforts to try to solve the problem on the question itself, that's why I asked. Please include what you tried and "failed".

Answer (score 4):

Iterate through the dictionary then use the `abs()` built-in function:

```
D = {'Milk': -5, 'eggs': 144, 'flour': -10, 'chocolate': -2, 'yeast': 5, 'Cornflower': 3}
for key, value in D.items():
   D[key] = abs(value)
print(D)
```

Output:

```
{'yeast': 5, 'Milk': 5, 'flour': 10, 'chocolate': 2, 'eggs': 144, 'Cornflower': 3}
```

If you want to do something else when the value is negative, use an `if` statement:

```
D = {'Milk': -5, 'eggs': 144, 'flour': -10, 'chocolate': -2, 'yeast': 5, 'Cornflower': 3}
for key, value in D.items():
   if value < 0:
       print('{} is negative'.format(key))
       D[key] = abs(value)
print(D)
```

Output:

```
chocolate is negative
Milk is negative
flour is negative
{'chocolate': 2, 'Cornflower': 3, 'Milk': 5, 'flour': 10, 'yeast': 5, 'eggs': 144}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use `abs()` to change the values to absolute values:

```
>>> {k: abs(v) for k, v in D.items()}
{'Milk': 5, 'eggs': 144, 'flour': 10, 'chocolate': 2, 'yeast': 5, 'Cornflower': 3}
```